# List<String> JUnit

Tags: java, junit

```
@Test
public void Test() {
    Tester rd = new Tester();

    Assert.assertSame(variable.getList(), ("banana, apple, pineapple"));
}
```

So variable.getList would return a List, so when I run the test there's going to be an error because ["banana, apple, pineapple"] is differente from "banana, apple, pineapple" .
how can I turn ("banana, apple, pineapple") into ["banana, apple, pineapple"]??

Comment: You can create a list to compare _Arrays.asList("banana", "apple", "pineapple")_

Comment: @Eklavya: in current Java, I'd suggest using `List.of` instead of `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: Wanna share this article :) [Modern Best Practices for Testing in Java](https://phauer.com/2019/modern-best-practices-testing-java/?fbclid=IwAR2p6SwiZdBkL0a4276JCQO2FcmZ1EVcGAkTyxM2kGE3rlwRileimqnEK1c#use-noverify-xx-tieredstopatlevel-1)

Comment: @JoachimSauer as I don't know which java version OP using I prefer to suggest _Arrays.asList_ in general

Comment: @Eklavya: fair enough. I just think that it's important to keep in mind that Java 8 is ancient and by default learners should aim to learn a recent version of a language and not be stuck back here with some of us experts who might be required to stay in the long before-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of: [`assertSame`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertSame(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) asserts that the two parameters reference the same object (i.e. it's equivalent to using `==`). This is *almost never* what you want to assert. It's much more likely you'll want to use `assertEquals()`.

Second, if you want to check if the result is equal to a List with three string object, then construct such a list with something like [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)):

```
Assert.assertEquals(variable.getList(), List.of("banana", "apple", "pineapple"));
```

If you are restricted to a Java version before Java 9, then [`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) is a good enough replacement for `List.of` in this case.

Comment: OP has `["banana, apple, pineapple"]`, which is the `toString()` of a list with a  single element with commas, not three elements

Comment: @Mureinik: that is why it isn't working. He says that `getList` returns a list and I strongly suspect it actually returns a list with three elements .

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd use `assertEquals` that tests for **equality** (i.e., uses the `equals` method) instead of `asssertSame`, what tests for **identity** (i.e., uses the `==` operator).

Second, instead of a string like you currently have, you'll need to wrap it in a `List`:

```
Assert.assertEquals(variable.getList(), Collections.singletonList("banana, apple, pineapple"));
```

Comment: Did you want to write `"banana", "apple", "pineapple"`?

Comment: @m0skit0 no - The OP shows `["banana, apple, pineapple"]`, which is the `toString` of a single-element list

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list instead of a fixed string.

```
final String[] expectedResult = new String[] { "banana", "apple", "pineapple" };
Assert.assertEquals(variable.getList(), Arrays.asList(expectedResult));
```